# How do I remove punctuation from a certain elements in a list of strings?

Tags: python, list

I've got a list (a line from a text file after I split it):

```
['41.2655469,', '-81.4565466', '6', '2000-09-18', '12:00:36', 'Jobs', 'needs', 'to', 'run', 'by', '...', "I'm" 'excited', 'to', 'see', 'movies', 'with', 'the', 'love', '...', 'WOW']
```

I'd like to remove all punctuation and change to .lower starting from the 5th element, in this case, from 'Jobs'. I've seen posts about removing punctuation from lists as a whole, but how would I address only specific elements? Also in doing so, is it possible to keep to same list (without making a new list)?

edit: I want to output only one list (the modified original list) which has .lower and punctuation removed for elements starting form the 5th element. I still want to keep the first 4 elements in this updated list, contrary to what I did above in my code.

Comment: Why do you want to use only one list?  A line of text is not going to be long enough to infringe on your available RAM.  The extra time spent in replacing individual list elements will use up all the time you would save with the intermediate list comprehensions.

Comment: The issue isn't time. The reason is that it'd be easier to relate the lists in future code; if I did what I did like my code in my question, that would create two lists, one with the first 4 elements and one without. I need to later be able to associate the first 2 elements (which are supposed to be coordinates) from one list with the rest of the elements (now without punc and all in lowercase) in the other list, and I'm not sure at all as to how to relate the indexes across two lists.

Comment: In that case, the central problem seems to be that you are not yet comfortable with the basic list operations: index, slice, append, extend.  Revisit your friendly neighborhood tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
import itertools as it

theList = ['41.298669629999999,', '-81.915329330000006', '6', '2011-08-28', '19:02:36', 'Work', 'needs', 'to', 'fly', 'by', '...', "I'm", 'so', 'excited', 'to', 'see', 'Spy', 'Kids', '4', 'with', 'then', 'love', 'of', 'my', 'life', '...', 'ARREIC']
rejected = [',', '.', '[', ']']
theList = list(filter(None, map(lambda l: l if theList.index(l) < 5 else ''.join(it.filterfalse(lambda x: x in rejected, l)).lower(), theList)))
```

It returns :

```
['41.298669629999999,', '-81.915329330000006', '6', '2011-08-28', '19:02:36', 'work', 'needs', 'to', 'fly', 'by', "i'm", 'so', 'excited', 'to', 'see', 'spy', 'kids', '4', 'with', 'then', 'love', 'of', 'my', 'life', 'arreic']
```

But you can adjust the list of rejected characters.

Comment: how would I remove empty elements?

Comment: but that changes the coordinate values. 41298669629999999 is far bigger than 41.298669629999999

Comment: Let's apply the filter from the index 5 only  to fix that (see my edited answer)